# can i use copyfield or dynamicfield or multivalued field functionality in solrnet?

Tags: solrnet

can any body explain how during indexing i can use  copyfield or dynamicfield or multivalued field functionality usin solrnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map multiValued fields to `ICollection<T>` properties:

```
[SolrField("features")]
public ICollection<string> Features {get;set;}
```

I just updated the [docs about mapping dynamicFields](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Mapping#Dictionary_mappings_and_dynamic_fields).

Comment: @Ahsan: yes, you can. There's nothing special about copyfields, you can fetch them just like any other field.