# How to access multi-valued dynamic fields with SolrNet?

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

How would you implement multi-valued dynamic fields with SolrNet?

I know with dynamic fields I can set them up like:

```
[SolrField("price_")]
public IDictionary<string, decimal> Price { get; set; }
```

And multivalued fields like:

```
[SolrField("fieldname")]
public ICollection<string> MyField { get; set; }
```

(thanks to [can i use copyfield or dynamicfield or multivalued field functionality in solrnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644627/can-i-use-copyfield-or-dynamicfield-or-multivalued-field-functionality-in-solrnet))

So I tried:

```
[SolrField("fqe_")]
public IDictionary<string, ICollection<string>> EqParam { get; set; }
```

Which failed when I tried adding the document.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of SolrNet are you using?

Comment: Sorry forgot that - version 0.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It works on the latest master](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/commit/f1b0d9f7fbe2b710213639c1754df4c8c14c9a79). I'm pretty sure it also works on 0.3.0b1 too. I highly recommend upgrading.

Comment: Thanks - I've updated the reference to 0.3.0b1 and it is running.